# Building query plan takes long time

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

For any request with a large number of JOINs (>3), the server takes a VERY long time to build the plan. It may take more than two hours to click on the Display Estimated Execution Plan button.

If I set option LOCK_TIMEOUT to 0, then I get error:

> lock request timeout exceeded

But what operation can block plan building?

This is a serious problem - can someone please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What if check actual (not estimated) plan? Also there is similar question on dba.stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279409/building-an-execution-plan-takes-too-long-on-sql-server , and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1027014/query-sp-running-very-slow-on-sqlserver-replicated

Comment: statistics update can do that

Comment: When the session is waiting for the plan to compile go to another session and see if it is waiting on something (`SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where session_id = @original_session_id`)